# Some questions about $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\sin ((2j+1)x)}{2j(2j-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\sin ((2j+1)x)}{2j(2j-1)}$. 
My questions are:

1. Can I say that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$?
2. Can I say that $f$ is continuous at any $x\in \mathbb{R}$?
3. How can I find an infinite series that converges to $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)dx$?

First, I know the series uniformly converges by Dirichlet's test. 
But I doubt if this uniform convergence gives me something useful. 
Intuitively, I think the answer for 1. and 2. are yes, but I have no idea with proving it rigorously. 
Would you help me?

Comment: Have you learned about the uniform limit theorem? It asserts that the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is also continuous.

Comment: A rule of thumb says that is the coefficients of a Fourier series are $O(\tfrac{1}{j^k})$, the resulting function is $C^{k-2}$ ; here with $k=2$ the function is therefore $C^0$, i.e., continuous.

Comment: @user429040 Oh, I think I can use it directly for 2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint for $1$: $f$ is bounded

Comment: For $3$, have you tried just literally integrating $f$ ? Since it converges uniformly you can interchange the infinite sum and the integral.

Comment: @DionelJaime Thank you, I solved 3, and it would be nice to use your comment to justify the solution. But still, I don't know I am doing well with 1. Is it okay to claim that 'f is bounded for all x' implies 'its domain is R'?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about the image. Yes the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.